# How to fix Failed to resolve xpath: no module found for prefix rfc1213-mib in module MODULE-MIB

Tags: xpath, opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang

I'm trying to execute mvn clean install on a Yang project (that I created on Eclipse with the Yang extension) to run the models.yang that I converted from MIB and generate the specifications. The problem is when the project reaches the file  MODULE-MIB.yang, I get this error:

[ERROR] yang-to-sources: Unable to generate sources with org.opendaylight.yangtools.maven.sal.api.gen.plugin.CodeGeneratorImpl generator
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to resolve xpath: no module found for prefix rfc1213-mib in module MODULE-MIB.

Looking at the yang code on MODULE-MIB, we have this path e.g.:

```
    leaf ifIndex {
        type leafref {
           path "/rfc1213-mib:RFC1213-MIB/rfc1213-mib:ifTable/rfc1213-mib:ifEntry/rfc1213-mib:ifIndex";
        }
    }
```

Reading the Yang model docs, I can't understand what is wrong. Anyone can give me a light here, please?

Comment: MODULE-MIB is most likely missing an import statement that specifies the `rfc1213-mib` prefix. Check this module's header statements.

Comment: rfc header: 
          module RFC1213-MIB { 
               namespace "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:yang:smiv2:RFC1213-MIB"; prefix"
               rfc1213-mib";

in the code scope, ifTablle, ifEntry, etc are specified.

MODULE-MIB has this section of code:

          import RFC1213-MIB {
                prefix "rfc1213-mib";
          }